# Can we add more than one domain name to a single IP in Route 53 (Aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-route53, domain-name, round-robin

Working on a project where I got 3 domains, eg; domain01.in, domain01dev.in, domaindev.in.

Here we have a single service hosted and routed to a single IP 158.x.x.x, now I want to access this service via any of the above-mentioned Domains!

Is there a way to do that on Route 53?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You just create three records to the same IP address. Depending on exact setup of yours, you can try with 3 different **A-type** [simple records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html) that point the same IP.